# Objective C read csv and populate in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, csv

Hi guys I am new to Objective C. I want to make an app where it can read a csv file locally and display the data in a specific column in the tableview.

1)Read csv locally

2)Display csv data (let's say fifth column "ItemName") in the tableview

Thanks for any advice.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *strPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"issues" ofType:@"csv"];
    NSString *strFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:strPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    if (!strFile) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading file.");
    }
    issues = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    issues = [strFile componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return[issues count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [issues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I figured it out in another way. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The way you do the parsing is only making columns of the whole file. First you need to separate by line-breaks (probably '\n'), then you can separate each line by ',' and each time take the 5th element and add it to an `NSMutableArray` (issues).

`[strFile componentsSeparatedByString:@","]` is not really CSV-parsing, there are more complex libraries available for that on cocoapods. If you need error-handling, etc. you better go with a library.